# Microsoft Graph GET /subscribedSku missing SKUs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to list all of the directly assigned licenses to a user via Microsoft Graph along with their friendly names.

I have found 3 ways to get a user's licenses:

- /users?$select=userPrincipalName,assignedLicenses
- /users/{id}/licenseDetails
- /users?$select=userPrincipalName,licenseAssignmentStates

The first two give me a list of the user's licenses, but they may not be assigned directly. So I'm looking to use the third one; which tells me if it is assigned via a group or not.

Interestingly, the third one also gives me MORE licenses in the response then the other two. Such as:

- 2b9c8e7c-319c-43a2-a2a0-48c5c6161de7 "AZURE ACTIVE DIRECTORY BASIC"
- efccb6f7-5641-4e0e-bd10-b4976e1bf68e "ENTERPRISE MOBILITY + SECURITY E3"

I want to have the full list of SKUs that may be assigned in the tenant. so for that I'm calling:

/subscribedSkus

but this call does not return the extra licenses that appeared when selecting "licenseAssignmentStates". I think it would be useful to have these as well.

**How can I retrieve the FULL list of skus along with their display names, available to the tenant.**

Helpful Links:

- User object:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0
- List Subscribed Sku: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscribedsku-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- License list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-service-plan-reference

Comment: For the mean time, I've decided to stick with the list from assignedLicenses, comparing it with the list from licenseAssignmentStates, to see if it is directly assigned or not. As it turns out, the additional licenses in licenseAssignmentStates do not appear in the Office365 portal either.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use licenseAssignmentStates to get the direct based licensing.  If the assignedByGroup is null that means it is a direct-assigned license.

Microsoft graph documentation on the user licenseAssignmentStates explains this at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/licenseassignmentstate?view=graph-rest-1.0